# Within the same group find and exclude records that have the same parent ID for certain types

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table like following:

```
GroupID    ParentID    Type

   1         ABC       IND
   1         ABC       IND
   1         CDE       ORD
   1         EFG       STD
   2         ZZZ       IND
   2         ZZZ       IND
   2         ZZZ       IND
   3         YYY       COR
   3         YYY       COR
```

I need to exclude those records that are in the same group, having the same parent ID and the type is IND or COR. But I need to keep those groups that have different parent ID and the type is not IND or COR.

So the result I want to get would be the following:

```
GroupID    ParentID    Type

   1         ABC       IND
   1         ABC       IND
   1         CDE       ORD
   1         EFG       STD
```

Somehow I am thinking to use 
`Rank () over(partition by GroupID order by ParentID)`, but it won't give me the results that I want.

Any thoughts? PS: This table has 5 Million+ records. Looking for the effective way to deal with it.

Thanks

Comment: Wait, what? I don't get your example at all...

Comment: how abc  ind come in result, if you need to exclude so

Comment: @PraveenPrasannan because in that group, there are three different parent IDs, and I need to keep them. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following gives you a list of the groupIDs you want to exclude

```
SELECT GroupID
FROM
(
  SELECT GroupID, 
         COUNT(DISTINCT ParentID) AS PCount, COUNT(DISTINCT TypeCode) as TCount,
         MAX(TypeCode) AS tCode
  FROM tablename
  GROUP BY GroupID
) t
WHERE PCount = 1 AND TCount = 1
   AND (tCode = 'IND' OR tCode = 'COR')
```

Now select everything else

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableName
WHERE GroupID not in (
  SELECT GroupID
  FROM
  (
    SELECT GroupID, 
           COUNT(DISTINCT ParentID) AS PCount, COUNT(DISTINCT TypeCode) as TCount,
           MAX(TypeCode) AS tCode
    FROM tablename
    GROUP BY GroupID
  ) t
  WHERE PCount = 1 AND TCount = 1
    AND (tCode = 'IND' OR tCode = 'COR')
)
```

Test with fiddle --> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f1d4f/15/0

Comment: Thanks for your help. But that doesn't work. If you are to count the parentID and type, you would have to group by those two columns. And it won't give me the result that I want. Example: In one group that has three rows and they are in a same type, two of them have the same parent ID and the other one has a different ID. From your code, it will exclude this group.

Comment: Sorry I forget to mention, there are 20 other columns in that table. My bad.

Comment: @Kric - fair my first version had some issues with grouping so there is some tested code for you.

Comment: @Kric - not sure of the point about 20 other columns.  Can't you abstract my solution to as many columns or rules you need?

Comment: Thanks.It's kinda hard to explain, I have to join other tables to roll up parent records to find if they are the types I want to exclude. Anyway,it works well!

Answer (score 0):

How is

```
 1         ABC       IND
```

in result set? here type is IND and you mentioned the result set should not have type IND or COR?

Comment: Sorry for the confusing wording. I want to keep those groups that have different parent IDs.

Comment: @AgentSQL - it is GroupIDs that only have those types that need to be excluded.